# how to set vibrancy value of UIVisualEffectView programmatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I added visual effect view with blur to my viewController in StoryBoard from object library

[image]

then I get reference to it

```
 @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView
```

but I want to set its vibrancy from false to true programmatically

[image]

from image above below the blur Style I want to check or set to on the vibrancy programmatically. Could anyone help me? any suggestion would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `effect` property. Not exactly a true/false, it takes a UIBlurEffect, or a UIVibrancyEffect. You can create a `UIVibrancyEffect` from a `UIBlurEffect` and assign that.

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .ExtraLight)
let vibrancy = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blur)

blurView.effect = vibrancy //with vibrancy
blurView.effect = blur //without vibrancy
```

Comment: oh thats turning it on, how about turning it off? cos im doing both programmatically, sorry for follow up question

Comment: Just assign the blur, not the vibrancy.

Comment: Cool i just threw it in a playground. Hopefully gets you going.